# JSON.stringify api response in express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm reading some codes and I saw this

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const {author, message} = req.body;

  if (author === undefined) {
    res.status(400);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Every message requires an author' }));
    return
  }

  res.redirect('/');

});
```

I've no clue why it need to use JSON.stringify, can't I just do `res.send({ message: 'Every message requires an author' })` ?

And the route has an unit test, it used JSON.parse

```
describe('when the author is blank', () => {
      it('renders an error message', async () => {
        const message = 'Server Testing';

        const response = await request(app)
          .post('/messages')
          .send({message});

        assert.equal(response.status, 400);
        assert.equal(JSON.parse(response.text).message, 'Every message requires an author')
        });
    });
```

I don't see the point of using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, please enlighten me.

Comment: you can simply remove, json.parse() and json.stringify() both.otherwise none.
probably there is some other reason, to make json into string format.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove but it may lead to some unexpected results at times even if you are passing exact json. I will share an example with you.
I was working on a project where in I need to send a hotel id in json format .I was sending the exact format but server was not accepting that and was throwing 500 error so it's always better to stay on a safer side and declare your data in a separate variable and pass in that data using json.stringify format in the get/post request.It comes good practices.
So it's always good to have those :-)

Answer (score 0):

Server side use:

```
res.json({a: 123})
```

instead of

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({a: 123}))
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Then in the unit test:

```
const response = await request(app).post('/messages').send({message});

const data = await response.json();
```